# The number of divisors of any positive number $n$ is $\le 2\sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-counting-function

How to prove that the number of divisors of any positive number $n$ is $\le 2\sqrt{n}$?

I have started something like below:

$$ n^{\tau(n)/2} =   \prod_{d|n} d$$

But not getting ideas on how to take this further and conclude. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/prove-that-dn-leq-2-sqrtn) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29544).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at most $\sqrt n$ divisors $d\mid n$ with $d\le \sqrt n$, and there are at most $\sqrt n$ divisors with $d>\sqrt n$ as each of them corresponds uniquely to a divisor $\frac nd<\sqrt n$.

Comment: short and simple ! thanks a lot you're the best xD