# to Show that $\tau(n) \leq 2\sqrt n$.

Tags: number-theory

The question is to Show that $\tau(n) \leq 2\sqrt n$. Am given the hint; if $d|n$, then one of $d$ or $n/d$ is less than or equal to $\sqrt n$. ($\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$) I just dont know how to start, pls any useful insight will be appreciated.

EDIT;
the only thy i could do was;
if $d$ and $d'$ are divisors of $n$ then, $d^2+(d')^2+2d \dot d'=(d+d')^2$ or $2d \dot d' \leq (d+d')^2$ or $\sqrt(2d \dot d') \leq (d+d')$ or $\sqrt(2n) \leq (d+d')$ and if we add up for all divisors we obtain $\tau(n)/2 \sqrt(2n) \leq \sigma (n)$

Comment: the trick is $$\sum_{d|n} 1 = \sum_{d|n, \ \ d < \sqrt{n}} 1 + \sum_{\frac{n}{d}|n,\ \  d \le \sqrt{n}} 1$$

Comment: finally $$\tau(n) = \sum_{d|n} 1 = 1_{n = a^2} + \sum_{d | n, \ \ d < \sqrt{n}} 2 $$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905170/the-number-of-divisors-of-any-positive-number-n-is-le-2-sqrtn?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your hint says it all. If $ n $ is not a perfect square, then the positive divisors can be divided into pairs, where the product of each pair gives $ n $. Then, the number of these pairs is at most $\sqrt{n}$, since each pair contains an element that is less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$. If $ n $ is a perfect square, the same reasoning works; in fact we have the tighter bound $2\sqrt{n} - 1 $.