# Upbounds for Ramanujan $\tau(n)$ function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For prime $p$, $|\tau(p)|\le 2p^{11/2}$.

I am looking for the upbound for $|\tau(n)|$,$n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thanks-
mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\tau(n)$ is a multiplicative function, i.e., satisfies $\tau(nm)=\tau(n)\tau(m)$ for all $m,n$ with $gcd(m,n)=1$, we obtain an upper bound simply by multiplying the bound for primes. If $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$. Then $|\tau(n)|=|\tau(p_1)|^{e_1}\cdots |\tau(p_r)|^{e_r}\le 2^r(p_1^{\frac{11}{2}e_1}\cdots p_r^{\frac{11}{2}e_r})$.

Furthermore one can show that
$$
|\tau(n)|≤n^{\frac{11}{2}}(\log (n))^{−1/2+o(1)}
$$
for a set of natural numbers $n$ of asymptotic density $1$. For details see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6606). This is better than the usual estimate
$$
|\tau(n)|\le d(n)n^{\frac{11}{2}}\le n^{\frac{11}{2}}(\log (n))^{\log(2)+o(1)}
$$
which holds for almost all $n$. Here $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I would like to use 
an upboud without $o(1)$ and without $\log(n)$. Can I write it as: $|\tau(n)|<2n^{a}$, $a>6$.

Comment: I suppose you want something for all $n\ge 1$. Then the nicest statement is $|\tau(n)|\le d(n)n^{\frac{11}{2}}$, proved by Deligne in $1974$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will then use $|\tau(n)|\le d(n)n^{\frac{11}{2}}<2n^{1/2}*n^{\frac{11}{2}}=2n^6$.

Comment: Good point - see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/prove-that-dn-leq-2-sqrtn).