# Finding $f$ satisfies $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tau(n)}{f(n)}=1$

Tags: number-theory, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Is there a known result on finding the function $f$ satisfies

> $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tau(n)}{f(n)}=1?$$
>   where $\tau(n)$ is the number of factor(s) of $n$.

Related:[Prove that $d(n)\leq 2\sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/prove-that-dn-leq-2-sqrtn)
It shows that $f(n)=O(\sqrt n)$.
**Some Ideas**
Also, letting $n=2^m,m\in\mathbb Z$ gives $f(n)=\Omega(m)$, or $f(n)=\Omega(\ln n)$.
Factorize $n$ into $\prod_ip_i^{\alpha_i}$ gives $\tau(n)=\prod_i(\alpha_i+1)$. So probably the next step to do is to estimate $p_i$.
Wikipedia gives $p_n\le n\ln n+n\ln\ln n$ when $n\ge 6$. Can we use this result to give the better bounds for $f$?

Comment: What function $f$ are you asking about?

Comment: @MartinR $f$ is an elementary function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best result in this direction is due to S. Wigert (1907):$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\tau (n) \log\log(n)}{\log(2)\log(n)}=1.$$
It comes as a corollary to certain estimates of $\max_{n\le x} \tau(n)$, the strongest of which is due to S. Ramanujan (1915).

Comment: Great, +1. Could you please point out which article is the result come from?

Comment: I recommend Ramanujan's article. It's called Highly Composite Numbers.